# How to use a variable from a function in a class

Tags: php

I have a function declared in another file. I need to get a variable from it and use it in the class. But for some reason an error appears.

```
$myvar = myfunc($text);//an error here
    
class func{
    public $title = $myvar;//and here
        public function ($title){
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you included the file where the function written? show your error with function please .

Comment: What is the error that appears?

Comment: You cant use `$myvar` inside the class, it doesn't exist in that scope. You need to inject it with a constructor or a setter function when you instantiate the class

Comment: @Al-Amin, yes:
`include inc.php;
$myvar = myfunc($text);
class func{`

Comment: @kerbh0lz, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$var' (T_VARIABLE) in /_class.func.php on line 231`

Comment: your error is throwing for another line of the code , its not for the line you are referring in the code snippet

Comment: @Al-Amin, this is an example :/                   `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$myvar' (T_VARIABLE) in /_class.func.php on line 231`

Comment: you can't access that variable from there as it is out of scope , i didn't notice that line in the class, @jameson2012 has already mentioned  it

Comment: There are two different errors here anyway, the error creating the hhe variable we can't see as you haven't show that code. The error for the class is because you are misusing member variables, suggest looking up class injection and member variables.  Because even if you fix the first issue, you can't assign member variables (properties) thus way

Comment: `public function ($title)`? That's also invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the return value of the function in the constructor when the object is being initialized.

```
include_once 'func.php';


class Myclass{

    public $title;

    function __construct( $title = null )
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}

$obj = new Myclass( getVar() );

echo $obj->title;
```

**func.php class**

```
<?php

function getVar()
{
    return 'this_var';
}

?>
```

Comment: Surely if the title is required it's better to inject this into the constructor as a dependency rather than hard code an external class.  What if we want to change the way we generate the title

Comment: I thought using the setter was appropriate here , but your suggestion is also helpful. thanks

Comment: a setter is fine, but a hard coded call to a class is the issue - that's not a good setter because it doesn't solve issue of if we want to change where/how we get the string from.  If the class needs a string title, it should get given one, it's not concerned with where it comes from

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about how to use a variable inside a class

```
class MyClass{
        
            public $title; //do not put a variable here, this is invalid
            ///you could set a default like this
            // e.g. public $title = "Jam";
            

            //this is a setter
            public function setTitle(string $title){
                $this->title = $title
            }

            public function getTitle() {
              return $this->title;
            }
      }
```

then use

```
$class = new MyClass();
$class->setTitle("jam sponge");
echo $class->getTitle();
```

or
define a constructor

```
  class MyClass{
            
            public $title;
            

            //this is a constructor
            public function __construct(string $title){
                $this->title = $title
            }

            public function getTitle() {
              return $this->title;
            }
      }
```

then use

```
$class = new MyClass("jam sponge");
echo $class->getTitle();
```

the latter is my preference.

As for this `$myvar = myfunc($text);//an error here` that's not relate to passing the var to the class.  You have some other issue in that function, so either show that code or post  anew question specific to it